# Custom back button in react-native error: params.handleThis is not a function(in params.handleThis(), params.handleThis is undefined)

Tags: javascript, android, ios, react-native, jsx

When you consecutively **press** Custom back button,

**error:**

> params.handleThis is not a function(in params.handleThis(), params.handleThis is undefined)
>   How do i resolve this?

i put  this.props.navigation.setParams in constructor and componentdidmount, but no success. below is the code:

```
        export default class PhysicalCounting extends BaseReact {

          constructor(props) {
            super(props);
            this.state = {
              scanningViewFocus: "",
              arrTotalAssets: [],
            };
            this.onBackPress = this.onBackPress.bind(this);
            this.props.navigation.setParams({
              handleThis: this.onBackPress.bind(this)
            });
          }

          static navigationOptions = ({ navigation }) => {
            const { params = {} } = navigation.state;
            return {
              title: "Physical Count",
              headerStyle: {
                backgroundColor: "#314097"
              },
              gesturesEnabled: false,
              headerTintColor: "#fff",
              headerLeft:
                <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => { params.handleThis() }}>
                  <Ionicons name={'ios-arrow-back'}
                    // title="Back"
                    color="#FFF"
                    style={{ paddingLeft: 20 }}
                    size={25}
                  />
                  {/* <Text>Back</Text> */}
                </TouchableOpacity>
            };
          };

          componentWillMount() {

            BackHandler.addEventListener('hardwareBackPress', 
           this.handleBackButtonClick);

            this.props.navigation.setParams({
              handleThis: this.onBackPress.bind(this)
            });

          }

          onBackPress() {
            if (this.state.startScan == true) {
              this.setState({
                startScan: false
              });
            } else {
              this.props.navigation.goBack(null);
            }
          }


          componentWillUnmount() {

            BackHandler.removeEventListener('hardwareBackPress', this.handleBackButtonClick);
          }

          handleBackButtonClick() {
            this.onBackPress()
            return true;
          }

        }
```

Comment: Did you try to console log your params? And I've never seen this `const { params = {} } = navigation.state;`. Can't find anything about it, can you give me the docs or where you've seen it?